# cygwin SSHD auto closes the connection upon connection

Tags: windows, ssh, cygwin, profile

I run cygwin/sshd on Windows Vista. I used to be able to use ssh to connect to my computer alright, until recently it started not working (I think I installed and removed some other cygwin packages)

For example, I would run

```
ssh localhost -l kizzx2
```

after keying in the password, I would be seeing this

```
Last login: Sat Dec  5 02:44:11 2009 from 127.0.0.1
Connection to localhost closed.
```

The strange problem is, if I connect using another account, I would be able to log-in alright! Which means:

```
ssh localhost -l Administrator
```

This would get me in an interactive shell!.

It looks like that some profile or environment settings of my user's profile is broken or something, but I don't want to re-build my user profile from scratch by creating a new account.

Any ideas?

*Update*: Just for information, I have tried replacing `~/.ssh` with clean one (let ssh build one from scratch). It didn't seem to do the trick.

Here's the full dump of running `ssh` with `-vvv`:

```
$ ssh localhost -p 22 -vvv
OpenSSH_5.1p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8l 5 Nov 2009
debug1: Reading configuration data /cygdrive/k/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /cygdrive/k/.ssh/identity type -1
debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /cygdrive/k/.ssh/id_rsa.
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type 'Proc-Type:'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type 'DEK-Info:'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug1: identity file /cygdrive/k/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /cygdrive/k/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.1 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.1
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour128,arcfour256,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour128,arcfour256,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour128,arcfour256,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour128,arcfour256,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 123/256
debug2: bits set: 516/1024
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug3: put_host_port: [127.0.0.1]:22
debug3: put_host_port: [localhost]:22
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename /cygdrive/k/.ssh/known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: match line 12
debug1: Host '[localhost]:22' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /cygdrive/k/.ssh/known_hosts:12
debug2: bits set: 521/1024
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /cygdrive/k/.ssh/identity (0x0)
debug2: key: /cygdrive/k/.ssh/id_rsa (0x1052b88)
debug2: key: /cygdrive/k/.ssh/id_dsa (0x0)
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: start over, passed a different list password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup keyboard-interactive
debug3: remaining preferred: password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug2: userauth_kbdint
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: userauth_kbdint: disable: no info_req_seen
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: 
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
kizzx2@localhost's password: 
debug3: packet_send2: adding 64 (len 58 padlen 6 extra_pad 64)
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug2: callback start
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug3: tty_make_modes: ospeed 38400
debug3: tty_make_modes: ispeed 38400
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel_input_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug2: channel_input_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
Last login: Sat Dec  5 02:44:11 2009 from 127.0.0.1
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eow
debug2: channel 0: close_read
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: channel 0: close_write
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r0 i3/0 o3/0 fd -1/-1 cfd -1)

debug3: channel 0: close_fds r -1 w -1 e 6 c -1
Connection to localhost closed.
Transferred: sent 1712, received 2104 bytes, in 0.2 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 6875.5, received 8449.8
debug1: Exit status 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got it working:

I was trying to get better debug output then `ssh -vvv`, so I tried running

```
/usr/sbin/sshd -d
```

to catch the output on screen. To my surprise, when I ran `sshd` like that (not as a service as I usually would with `net start sshd`), I could log in as any user alright.

That led me to believe that the problem lied in the way the service was set up. So I deleted the service and ran the config script again. Bam! It's done!

```
cygrunsrv -R sshd
ssh-host-config
# it's fixed!
```

**Edit**: It looks like that the reason is that the privilege separation user cannot be *disabled* in Windows. It used to be OK for me to disable that privilege separation user and still get it to work, but oh well.

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical effect of running the `ssh-host-config` script once, using typical default selections. What happens is that two new Cygwin user accounts are created, but their settings in /etc/passwd (and possibly /etc/groups) seem temporary. After first run you have the SHELL set to /bin/false and if you compare this to `mkpasswd -l -u cyg_server` you will see /bin/bash. So either logoff and logon as  and run Cygwin as admin, or just make the change in /etc/passwd and restart sshd service.

Answer (score 0):

in your cygwin path what does your user in etc/passwd look like? it is possible a missing/bad shell path or no access to your home directory would cause this behavior. Check the permissions on your cygwin path home/kizzx2 folder too.

Comment: What do you mean by "In your cygwin path"? I checked the /etc/passwd file which looks normal. I know it would be difficult to debug without posting everything on my system.

The thing that bothers me is that `/var/log/sshd.log` doesn't contain any useful information. Is there anyway I can obtain more useful information? (because -vvv gives exit status )

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting the "CYGWIN service" log-on user (if it's other than the default SYSTEM) in the "Administrators" group, and then restart the service.